# SQL Error (137): Must declare the scalar variable from HeidiSQL

Tags: sql-server-2012, heidisql

I don't really see where I'm going wrong with this fairly simple query:

```
DECLARE @id int;
SET @id = 84;

INSERT INTO Activity_Ax_Account_Numbers
VALUES(@id,'N/A');

INSERT INTO Activity_Files
VALUES(@id,0x66696C6C65722073747566660D0A,'Filler',0);

INSERT INTO Activity_Settings
VALUES(@id,0,0,0);
```

I have to do the above a couple of times as I need to transfer data from an old database to a new one by hand (Don't ask, that's just how it is T_T). So the above is something I'm going to do a lot and instead of doing this by hand I thought I could just make a simple query I could run as then I only have to do one row of data by hand for every entry instead of four.

But I get the error in the title when I try to execute the query. It's an MS SQL 11.0 server that I connect to via HeidiSQL.

Comment: Is 66696C6C65722073747566660D0A supposed to be a varchar?

Comment: `INSERT INTO Activity_Files
VALUES(@id,'66696C6C65722073747566660D0A','Filler',0);`

Comment: @RahulTripathi it's not a varchar it's a varbinary. But even then I still get the same error if I do the above.

Comment: Relying on implicit order of column names in an INSERT statement is a big mistake. Always supply the column names in an INSERT statement: Write `INSERT INTO <tablename>(<column_name_1>, ..., <column_name_N>) VALUES (<value_1>, ..., <value_N>);`.

Comment: Do any triggers or similar exists on the tables? Might be the error message is from something else happening when you run your query?

Comment: @AllanS.Hansen No there are no triggers at all.

Comment: Which of the above statements throws the error?

Comment: The first "Values" statement.

Comment: Are you running the whole batch, or just selecting that first statement and pressing ctrl-E to run it separately from SSMS?

Comment: It appears that HeidiSQL might just not be able to deal with that syntax.

Comment: Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8567222/how-to-update-a-varbinary-field-with-a-specific-value). `Salt=CAST('bPftidzyAQik' AS VARBINARY),`